# How to move div down or up ?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, top div has style as follows:

```
.context_left {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:775px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    min-height:450px;
    margin-bottom:20px;   
}
```

while that the div below it has style:

```
  .footer {
        width:100%;
        height:54px;
        display:block;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top:80px;
        left:0;   
  }
```

when the div context_left changes it's height the div footer remains at it's position, I want to move the footer div down if context_left div changes it's height. Can anyone please help me to do it?

Comment: As long as you have your footer in absolute positioning it won't be affected by the flow. Without a clear idea of the structure I can't recommend anything but start by removing the absolute position from .footer. Maybe clear it too, in case .context_left flows into it.

Comment: Creating a fiddle will help to understand the actual problems other than position:absolute in footer

Comment: Would it look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/tLueq/?

Comment: kindly check my layout structure at http://jsfiddle.net/VWcYt/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add this lign to your .footer

```
  clear:both;
```

And delete
    position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    height:54px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:80px;
    left:0;   
}
```

Removed the `position: absoulte` from footer. Try this. Because the footer will remain at the same position till position:absolute remains in style.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your footer with position: absolute;. That means your footer should be kinda fixed, but inheriting from its parent.

Try changing absolute to relative and see if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
 .context_left {
        float:left;
        width:775px;
        padding-left:10px;
        margin-top:20px;
        min-height:450px;
        margin-bottom:20px;  
        display:inline-block;

    }


      .footer {
            width:100%;
            height:54px;
            display: block;
            clear:both;
            margin-top:80px;
            left:0;   

      }
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dMawS/show

Comment: i do not want to have spaces or margins on left and right sides, because of this i have used position: absolute; by removing this i am unable to do what i want, so as far as i know there is no other method to do it.

Comment: For that you can add `margin:0;` to body. see updated fiddle. @nouman

Comment: kindly check my layout structure http://jsfiddle.net/VWcYt , adding margin:0; to body is not working for me. @Avin Varghese

Answer (score 0):

If a sticky footer at the bottom of the page is, what your looking for, then this can help you:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    /* the margin compensates the footer plus the footer's top margin */
    margin: 0 0 134px 0;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
}
```

The footer will always be at the bottom of the browser's viewport *or* below the content.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwh8M/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new ResizeObserver in JavaScript. It has a "callback" parameter, and a "observe()" method who has a "target" parameter. Try this, it completely precise.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div001{position:absolute;top:20px;left:0.2cm; height:300px;width:12cm;background:blue;resize:both;overflow:auto;}
#div002{position:absolute;top:350px;bottom:0.2cm;width:12cm;background:gray;resize:both;overflow:auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='div001'>Texte de la div</div>
<div id="div002"></div>
<script>
const dv001 = document.querySelector("#div001");
const dv002 = document.querySelector("#div002");
var observer = new ResizeObserver(()=>{dv002.style.top = dv001.clientHeight+30+"px";});
observer.observe(dv001);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/phzc6qw0/